# Export/import gboard data

Tags: settings, backup, data-transfer, xiaomi, gboard

I want to find way how one may export and import data from gboard app.

I want to make backup of my data and in future have an ability to move my words to a new phone

Also, I need an way to mass-add done words and remove some of my misspellings that gboard keeps recommending after I used them.

In case that it is relevant - I am using a Xiaomi Redmi 4 phone, without root access.

Comment: To delete currently presented suggestion one may long-press the word in top row and move it to a bin that will appear.